# SpriteKitNode Background Color

Tags: ios, swift, background, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am building a card game and have an image for the texture of my SpriteKit node. The image is a pdf image for the card artwork and I want to set the background color of the card (The blank space around the artwork). The image I have is just the artwork of the card and does not have any background detail. How can I set a background to this? Setting the "color" attribute in the SKSpriteNode init only changes the color of my image object. How can I access the color and the texture of the "blank space" behind the image while remaining in the width and size set in the super.init?

I don't want to change all my pdfs and add a white layer to the back because I may want to have some custom color changes for the background of the card while the game is playing. I have tried adding a SKShapeNode inside the init function (Example below), but that technically overlays on top of my Card SKSpriteNode and then the user can't click on the actual "Card". It seems like this should be fairly straightforward, but I have had a lot of trouble.

```
import SpriteKit

class Card: SKSpriteNode {

    init(image: String) {
        super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: image), color: .clear,
                   size: CGSize(width: K.cardSize[0], height: K.cardSize[1]))

        //Background
        let background = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: K.cardSize[0], height: K.cardSize[1]), cornerRadius: 15)
        background.fillColor = UIColor.white
        background.zPosition = -10
        addChild(background)
    }

}
```

Comment: You have zPosition set so that the background should be behind the card, which looks right.  If you're talking about user interaction, which nodes are handling the interaction (have `isUserInteractionEnabled` set)?  Perhaps you're handling the touch somewhere higher in the tree instead of on the card and are using `atPoint`, which returns the deepest child (in this case the background)?  If the latter, fixes include using `nodes(at:)`, taking the touched background's parent, or letting `Card` handle the user interaction.

Comment: No need for an SKShapeNode,  Use an SKSpriteNode with the color and size init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 SKSpriteNodes like this

```
class Card: SKSpriteNode {

    init(imageName: String) {
       let card = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:imageName)
       //Create the rounded corner image without resorting to SKShapeNode
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(card.size)
           let context =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
           context.clear(rect)
           context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
           let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size:size)
           let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:rect, cornerRadius:0.15)
           path.fill()
           let image = context.makeImage();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

       super.init(texture:SKTexture(cgImage:image))        

       card.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
       addChild(card)
    }

}
```

This will now treat your card image more like a texture than an interactive node.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great! The only thing that didn't work for me was the rounded corners. I got an error with your "bezierPathWith...". It wanted just "roundedRect" as a parameter. I passed my rect to that parameter, but the final product came out with sharp corners still. Any thoughts?